# A question about sampling distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Assume there are $n$ independent random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ and i wonder why the sample variance is $S^2=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \ (X_i-X)^2}{n-1}$ where $X$=$\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}{n}$ instead of $S^2=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\ (X_i-X)^2}{n}$.

Comment: i think there should be some derivation right?

Comment: Did you try to compute the expectation of $S^2$ in both cases? (And please add some squares in your formulas.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have said that $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are independent, but not added, as most people do, that they are also *identically distributed* (or at the very least, have the same mean and variance).  With this added condition, we have
$$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X)^2\right] = (n-1)\sigma^2$$
where $\sigma^2$ is the common variance of the $n$ random variables. Thus,
*defining* the sample variance as
$$S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X)^2$$
has the nice property that $E[S^2] = \sigma^2$.
As Didier Piau has already suggested to you in a comment, you should
work out the expectation calculation for yourself.

You might also want
to try and work out what happens when the $X_i$ have the same mean $\mu$
but different variances $\sigma_i^2$, and also when they have
different means $\mu_i$ and variances $\sigma_i^2$.

Comment: $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X)^2\right] = (n)\sigma^2$$ there are n terms so $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X)^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n} E\left[(X_i-X)\right] = (n)\sigma^2$$(since all of them have the same varience) but i cant figure out why the answer is (n-1) $\sigma^2$

Comment: No, since $E[X_i]=\mu=E[X]$, $X_i-X$ is a zero-mean random variable, and so $\text{var}(X_i-X)=E[(X_i-X)^2]$ can be computed as $$\begin{align*}\text{var}(X_i-X)&=\text{var}(X_i)+\text{var}(X)-2\text{cov}(X_i,X)\\&=\sigma^2+\frac{\sigma^2}{n}-2\text{cov}(X_i,X)\\&=\frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2.\end{align*}$$ I will leave it to you to work out why $\text{cov}(X_i,X)=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. Putting it all together, $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-X)^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n} E\left[(X_i-X)^2\right] = (n-1)\sigma^2.$$ Note that _your_ assertion is missing a square in the middle sum.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Wikipedia article about this: [Bessel's correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction).  (I wrote some of it myself, but in this case others did most of it.)

Bessels correction eliminates bias.  Eliminating bias is sometimes a very bad idea, as I explained in this paper: "An Illuminating Counterexample, *American Mathematical Monthly*, volume 110, number 3 (March, 2003), pages 234-238.